# How to display RoR app code version on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, version-control, heroku

For my Rails apps I normally deploy to production from a tagged version, and then display the tag in the user interface assigning the output of `git describe --always` to a variable in `config/application.rb`.

Now I'm moving an app over to Heroku, and deployment to heroku only happens using the master branch, so this trick won't work any more.

Are there any other ways to assign a version number to my code and display it on the UI when I've deployed to heroku?

Thanks,
Stewart

Answer (score 3):

You can add a variable to the Heroku configuration by running this command locally whenever you push new changes to Heroku:

```
heroku config:add GIT_TAG=`git describe --always`
```

Then you can access this in your app's configuration:

```
version = ENV['GIT_TAG'] || `git describe --always`
```

When the app is running on Heroku, it will pick up the config variable (`ENV['GIT_TAG']`) and when it's running locally in development it will fall back to running `git describe --always`.

You will need to update the Heroku config variable each time you deploy, but I generally add this kind of thing to a deploy script or rake task (along with useful things like creating a new tag marking the deploy and running any new database migrations on Heroku).

Comment: Yeah, but since I'm pushing *master* to heroku, `git describe` doesn't have my git tag in it.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear:  You should run the `heroku config:add` command locally when you push a new version.  The Ruby code will pick up the `GIT_TAG` environment variable when running on Heorku, and will fall back to running the `git describe` command when running locally in development.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't `git tag` fit your needs?

And why wouldn't the old trick work anymore?

Comment: Because I push to heroku off master, so it doesn't have any of the tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display it on the UI then a git SHA output probably isn't particularly useful - you have two options, set a Heroku config variable with a user friendly version number in or a set a version number in your code that you increment when you deploy from master. You could probably wrap the deploy up in a rake task that incremented the version number either a file (and then readded it to git and commits it) or simply increments a value in a config variable.

Also, don't forget Heroku release management http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2010/11/17/releases/ which you may also be able to employ here to get the version number from that perhaps.

Comment: Yeah I think I'll need to go with a non-git solution like this. Or just get rid of the version number all together.