# Reset Version Tags Heroku

Tags: git, heroku

Right now on Heroku my app is v62, I just put it into private beta, so it should theoretically be v0, is there any way I can reset the version tag on heroku?

Comment: As in http://stackoverflow.com/q/10777881/6309, isn't it just a matter of setting `GIT_TAG`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are talking about the release tag that Heroku applies whenever you deploy or make addon changes to your application? Heroku manage this so you can perform rollbacks etc it's not something that you can reset. If you want to manage versions I would suggest using a true git tag and then deploying the tagged version to Heroku and keeping reference of what is tagged.

Comment: Ok, I was looking at the heroku dashboard, I guess that makes sense, I just wanted to make sure that the version tagging didn't mean anything other than that. Thanks